# Can we access docker images, containers from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, docker

I have requirement from testing to access the docker images and containers via eclipse, since the testing team wants to access docker containers via eclipse.

I am referring to this [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmhEZiS26os)
i was able to configure the same, but was not able to see docker image or containers in eclipse.

I have installed docker on windows 10 on Desktop box.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker version                                                                                                                                                     Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.4
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.10
 Git commit:        9013bf5
 Built:             Thu Oct 17 23:44:48 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.4
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.10
  Git commit:       9013bf5
  Built:            Thu Oct 17 23:55:51 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Any help on this

Thanks
Sanjeev Kumar N